# C# WPF using Caliburn.Micro: How can I convert an IEnumerable to BindableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, ienumerable, caliburn.micro

I'm following a guide on connecting a C# project to an SQLite database. Here's the link to that guide: https://youtu.be/ayp3tHEkRc0?t=1765

My code is very similar to what's created in the video. However, I'm recreating the project using a framework called CaliburnMicro. My understanding of CaliburnMicro is it 'automates' some data binding by taking advantage of identical names of model properties and UI components.

The model I'm using in my project is of type BindableCollection<> as recommended in another of Tim Corey's tutorials. That is the type into which I'd like to convert my database query results.

The guide says that the result of the data query is an IEnumerable. He converts it into a List<> type using an inbuilt method. However, there isn't such a method to convert to CaliburnMicro's BindableCollection<> type.

```
    public static BindableCollection<PersonModel> LoadPeople()
    {
        using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
        {
            var output = cnn.Query<PersonModel>("SELECT * FROM Person", new DynamicParameters());

            return output.ToBindableCollection()
        }
    }
```

My question is, how can I convert the IEnumerable result to BindableCollection<> data type? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static BindableCollection<T> ToBindableCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
   {
       return new BindableCollection(source);
   }
}
```

Comment: Very good thanks. public static BindableCollection<PersonModel> LoadPeople()
{
            using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
            {
                var output = cnn.Query<PersonModel>("SELECT * FROM Person", new DynamicParameters());
                return Extensions.ToBindableCollection(output);
            } }     public static class Extensions
{
        public static BindableCollection<PersonModel> ToBindableCollection(this IEnumerable<PersonModel> source)
 {
            return new BindableCollection<PersonModel>(source);
        }  }